# insertion >> operator overload: exception handling when retrieving object's ctor parameters from cin

Tags: c++, constructor, exception, operator-overloading, istream

Here is an example of possible user input that is considered valid:

```
(-12.444,34.55) (2.0,-44.4444)
```

---

... invalid input, `)` is missing:

```
(23.33,-234.5555 (-23.33, 44.1)
```

---

### Complex.cpp : ctor

```
Complex (double real = 1.0, double imag = 0.0 );
```

### Complex.cpp : Exception class

```
class Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value: public std::invalid_argument {

public:
  Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value():std::invalid_argument("Invalid value for inputting Complex # using Mode 1"){}
};
```

### insertion operator overload:

```
istream & operator >> (istream & input, Complex & obj) {

  input.ignore(2,'('); // skip over '('

  input >> obj.real_part; // read the real component of the Complex #

  // Process ','
  if (input.peek() == ',') {
    input.get(); // swallow ','
  }
  else {

    input.flags(origFormat); // restore format flags

    input.clear();

    throw Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value();
  }

  // Process imaginary part

  // read the imaginary component of the Complex #
  input >> obj.imaginary_part;

  // Process ')'
  if (input.peek() == ')') {
    input.get(); // swallow ')'
  }

  else {

    input.flags(origFormat); // restore format flags

    input.clear();

    throw Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value();
    }

  }
  // restore format flags
  input.flags(origFormat);

  return input; // enables  cin >> a >> b >> c
}
```

### Main.cpp : try / catch :

```
Complex A,B; // Create Complex objects: 

// My question is regarding the cascading objects in the try block

cout << "\nEnter 2 Complex numbers in the form \"(real_value,imaginary_value)\" :\n";
try     
{
  cin >> A >> B;
}
catch(const Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value & invalidMode1Exception) 
{
  cerr << "\nException occurred: " << invalidMode1Exception.what() << endl;
}
```

I don't quite understand how exception handling occurs in the try block: cascading objects with the insertion operator. What are some scenarios that may occur and how to implement better practices.

A: if object A receives erroneous input 
  B: if object A is okay, however object B receives erroneous input 
  C: valid double values provided, however incorrect format is provided

Comment: Is your question about what the state of objects is after an exception is thrown, or about how to handle the exception properly?

Comment: I am mostly interested in the objects' states and how exactly the compiler deals with those objects and such states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If reading object `A` throws an exception, `A` is in some unknown state, `B` is left unchanged.
2. If reading object `A` succeeds but reading object `B` throws an exception, `A` is in a good state, `B` is in some unknown state
3. Well the incorrect formatting is where the exceptions are thrown. However, if the `double`s can't be read, there will be some part left on the stream, and reading the formatting will fail.

You should add a check of the stream state after reading each `double`, to check it succeeded:

```
input >> obj.real_part;
if (!input) throw Invalid_Mode1_Complex_Value();
```

You should read up on [exception safety guarantees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety). Here you can offer *strong* exception safety on the `Complex` by reading into some local variable, then assigning that into `obj` only if the read succeeds. (You still only offer *basic* exception safety on the stream).

```
std::stream& operator>> (std::istream& input, Complex& obj) {
    Complex tmp;

    // ...
    input >> tmp.real_part;
    if (!input) throw //...
    // ...

    obj = tmp; // if we got to here, we know tmp is properly formed
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bob, very thorough and helpful answer. Clarified all of my questions!